# Idemtracker between article or inbook and book with cite command in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have a problem when I cite an article following a book, it seems that the idemtracker doesn't work for documentclass as article or inbook.

Example :
biblioessai.tex :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,citestyle=verbose-trad2,backend=biber,uniquename=false,citepages=suppress]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\addbibresource{essai.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{article1}

\cite{article2}

\cite{book}
\end{document}
```

essai.bib :

```
@article{article1,
author = "My Author",
journal = "A Journal",
title = "Titletitle",
date = "2005",
pages = "49-62",
volume = "12",
number = "1-2"
}

@book{book,
address = "Address",
author = "My Author",
origyear = "1994",
pagetotal = "349",
publisher = "A publisher",
title = "An other title",
year = "2004"
}

@article{article2,
author = "My Author",
journal = "A Journal",
title = "An other article",
date = "2008",
pages = "51-63",
volume = "1",
number = "15"
}
```

After compilation i have :

> My Author. *Titletitle*. Dans : A Journal 12.1-2 (2005)
>   My Author. *An other article*. Dans : A Journal 1.15 (2008)
>   My Author. *An other title*. Address : A publisher, 2004

And what I would like :

> My Author. *Titletitle*. Dans : A Journal 12.1-2 (2005)
>   Idem. *An other article*. Dans : A Journal 1.15 (2008)
>   Idem. *An other title*. Address : A publisher, 2004

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want that bibstyle? It's a bit inconsistent to have a nearly fullcite but only shorten the author with `idem`. That's why the verbose-styles don't do that per default. (See my answer.)

Comment: I am writing a thesis in french and unfortunately, the french norms are very different from american norms, maybe that's why this surprise you. But, in our norms, we have to present two cites of the same auther in this way even if the reference was not cited before. We use "idem" when different references of the same author are cited consicutively.

Comment: I understand, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" here is that `verbose-trad2` always prints a fullcite if a cite is seen for the very first time. *After that* `idem`/`ibidem` etc. will work.

See the definition of bibmacro `cite` in `verbose-trad2.cbx`.

So if you repeat in your code

```
\cite{article1}
\cite{article2}
\cite{book}
```

the `idem` will show up.

---

**EDIT**:
Since you need the `idem` to show up fullcites, too, it's maybe best to modify the author macro itself:

Add the following lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{author}{\printnames{author}}{\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}%
{\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}{\printnames{author}}}{}{}
```

This will exchange the `\printnames{author}` command from `authortitle.bbx` (which is used by verbose-trad2) with a test if it's a `idem` or not and use the appropriate macro.

I don't know if it's the best solution, but for your MWE it works. Maybe you have also to exchange the `editor` macro and others as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know how i could have the hoped result ?

Comment: You're welcome. But instead of saying 'thank you' you should upvote and accept the answer (if it answers your question). See here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers